# How can I render HTML content with variables in VueJS received by AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to realize that some content is loaded dynamically via POST request (also for explanation I created static method) and with vue variables in HTML.

HTML is generated via serverside in PHP.

**Problem: dynamicContent is rerendered with default values when some of v-model inputs are changed outside of component.**

Steps to reproduce:

1. Press STATIC or POST button
2. Will be loaded component. Change input value from 5 to any other
3. Update amount input from 7 to any other, and dynamic content will be reset to default (input value resets to 5).

Code example:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>1. Press STATIC or POST button</p>
  <button @click="updateContentStatic">STATIC</button>
  <button @click="updateContentPost">POST</button>
  <p>2. Will be loaded component. Change input value from 5 to any other</p>
  <component :is="dynamicContent && {template:dynamicContent}"></component>
  <p>3. Update amount input, and dynamic content will be reset to default.</p>
  <input type="text" v-model="amount">
</div>

<script>
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    amount: '7',
    dynamicContent: '',
  },
  methods: {
    updateContentPost() {
      $.post({ url: '/test123',
        success: function(data) { app.dynamicContent = data; }
      });
    },
    updateContentStatic() {
        app.dynamicContent = '<div><input value="5"> Amount {{ $root.amount }}</div>';
    },
    updateAmount() {
        this.amount = 10001;
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/fe6znjrs/1/

Comment: I'm guessing you need `<input :value="$root.amount">`? https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/1s830tcu/

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, with v-model in input it is working: https://jsfiddle.net/rq72zmkL , but how can I realize it without any vue tags in input? (If i only have input with value from database as in example)